# change text false and true javascripts

Tags: javascript, text, replace, greasemonkey

text replace "false" to "true"

ori from html (dont change) :

```
<td  align="center">false</td>
```

to

```
<td  align="center">true</td>
```

my js code error :

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<td  align=\"center\">false<\/td>/g,"<td  align=\"center\">true<\/td>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PKM6U/

Comment: don't use regex to parse html it will always be a headache

Comment: how? iam newbie sir in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to this I would recommend you use a framework/library to make thing easier for you

jQuery have a nice selector that will help you with this

http://jquery.com/
http://jquery.com/download/
http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

This code will do what you want

```
function swapTrueFalse(){
    if($("td[align=center]:contains('true')"){
        $("td[align=center]:contains('true')").text('false')
    }else if($("td[align=center]:contains('false')"){
        $("td[align=center]:contains('false')").text('true')
    }
}
```

I would suggest you add a class to the element however as this will make it more efficient:

```
<td  align="center" class='true-false'>true</td>
```

Change the code to match:

```
function swapTrueFalse(){
    var t = $(".true-false").text()
    if(t === "true"){
        $(".true-false").text("false");
    }else{
        $(".true-false").text("true");
    }
}
```

Using regex to parse HTML in the way you are is extremely inefficient so I do advise against it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td  align="center" id="changeme">false</td>
```

in js

```
document.getElementById("changeme").text="true"
```

Comment: this js code in fiddle : `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<td  align=\"center\">false<\/td>/g,"<td  align=\"center\">true<\/td>");` i want innerHTML.replace not getElementById or add id (ori html)

Comment: Inspect the DOM element of false in your fiddle... its not well formed..  <body> false    <body>  this is the DOM formed for your code

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine if you replace your all "td" with "span". Having td nodes by themselves doesn't really make sense and it appears as though they disappear completely after the fiddle is ran.